# javascript password match if not match show in innerHTML

Tags: javascript

hi you write that code that is helpful for me but i want to show message in innerHTML when password not match how to do this i am trying but not working for me.below is my code .please guide me. i am beginner learner.

```
                if (pwd != cpwd) {

                 document.getElementById("pwd").innerHTML="password must be match";
     document.getElementById("cpwd").innerHTML="password must be match";
     document.getElementById("pwd").style.color="RED";

      return false;
```

}

i want to know about how to exactly write in innerHTML

below your code

```
               <input id="pass1" type="password" placeholder="Password" style="border-radius:7px; border:2px solid #dadada;" /> <br />
               <input id="pass2" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" style="border-radius:7px; border:2px solid #dadada;"/> <br />

 <script>
function myFunction() {
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    if (pass1 != pass2) {
        //alert("Passwords Do not match");
        document.getElementById("pass1").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
        document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    }
    else {
        alert("Passwords Match!!!");
    }
}
```

Sumbit

Thanks for advance 
waiting for your appreciate answer.

Comment: [Your code seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/UA9q8/). What are `cpwd` and `pwd`? What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: Where u want to put actually ..Where is your " pwd " and " cpwd " element

Answer (score 1):

You should use the event `onBlur` tied to the field "pass2" in order trigger the first code snippet attached to your question.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("pass2").onblur=function(){
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    if (pass1 != pass2) {
      document.getElementById("pass1").innerHTML="password must be match";
      document.getElementById("pass2").innerHTML="password must be match";
      document.getElementById("pass1").style.color="RED";
      return false;
     }
     return true;    
};
```

Another option is to tie it to the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Add a div to store your password validation response to the document like `<div id='validate'></div>` and then after you have checked for passwords match, you can display the appropriate result in the html of this div 
`document.getElementById('validate').innerHTML="passwords do not match!";`